# How to display frames of a video file as gif in Jupyter notebook without writing file

Tags: python, video, jupyter-notebook, gif

How do I read in a video file and show frames of that video as a gif animation in a Jupyter notebook without writing to file?

Answer (score 1):

This answer combines multiple answers about reading a video file and converting it in memory to a gif and how to display this bytes object inside a Jupyter environment. I'm sorry, but I couldn't find again all the resources I used.

```py
import imageio
import skimage
import cv2
from IPython.display import Image
from io import BytesIO

file = "video.mkv"
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(file)

frames = list()
for frame_no in range(10):
    capture.set(1, frame_no)
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    assert ret
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    frames.append(frame)
gif_file = BytesIO()
imageio.mimsave(gif_file, [skimage.img_as_ubyte(frame) for frame in frames], 'GIF', fps=2)
Image(data=gif_file.getvalue())
```